# 2 sql in one php while loop

Tags: php, mysql, html

I'm a bit of a novice to PHP and MySQL.  I'm creating my own little news blog for the heck of it.  I got to display the information I wanted, but what I want to do is count the number of comments.  I made 2 tables, the first table is the article and the other is the comments.  I not to sure of how to figure this out.  Can anyone help?

```
$input_now1 = "SELECT blog_entries.id, blog_entries.posted, blog_entries.subject, blog_entries.quicktext
  FROM blog_entries
  ORDER BY blog_entries.posted DESC
  LIMIT 0, 3;";

$result1 = mysql_query($input_now1);

?>
<div id="middle">

  <div id="box1">
    <?php
      while($record1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1))
      {
        ?> 
        <h2 style="padding-top:5px;"><?php echo $record1['subject']; ?></h2>
        <div id="header1" style="position:relative;"></div>
        <div id="maintext" style="position:relative;">
          <p><?php echo $record1['quicktext']; ?></p>
          <a href="blog_articles.php?ID=<?php echo $record1["id"];?>">View Article - <?php echo date("D jS F Y g:iA",strtotime($record1["posted"]));?></a>
        </div>
        <div id="text_footer"></div>
        <?php 
      }
      mysql_free_result($result1);
    ?>
  </div>
  <?php
    include 'include/sidebar.php';
  ?>        

</div>
```

Table1 blog_entries: 
id 
posted 
subject 
body 
quicktext

Table2 blog_comments: 
id 
blog_id 
posted 
name 
comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'd need to know your database schema to be sure, but it's probably something like this...

```
SELECT COUNT(comment.id) AS numcomments,
    entry.id,entry.posted,entry.subject,entry.quicktext
FROM `blog_comments` comment, `blog_entries` entry
WHERE comment.blog_id=entry.id
GROUP BY entry.posted, entry.subject, entry.quicktext
```

Comment: Table1: blog_entries
id 
posted
subject
body
quicktext

Table2: blog_comments
id 
blog_id
posted
name
comment

Comment: @blackbull7: you should put that in the original question, in a more readable format.  I've updated my answer to match your schema.

Comment: I updated the question.  How who I be able to pull it off with a while loops in php or do I use another function?

Comment: @blackbull77: That query doesn't require a loop: it gets the count for all entries.  I don't really understand what you're asking now.  If you want to get the number of comments for a *particular* entry, just `SELECT COUNT(id) FROM blog_comments WHERE blog_id=foo`.

Comment: I'm not talking about SQL.  I'm talking about display the comment count in PHP.  Right now, $record1 is looping 3 of the articles, how do I display the second query showing the number of comments when $record1 is using a while function in PHP?

Comment: @blackbull77: You're not doing anything with the blog_comments table.  Until you do another query that extracts some information from that table, it's not possible for PHP to know how many comments there are.

Comment: I made another answer below to help show you what I'm trying to do.  Hope it helps.

Comment: @blackbull77: Ah.  Updated to do it in a single query.

Answer (score 1):

I would just add something like this anywhere within boundary of the loop, kind of move your code around. After loop starts you will collect ID then you'll be able to run COUNT against and echo the specific count. Not been a loop it will not process unless the loop has ran again...

```
    <?php       
    $input_now2 = "SELECT COUNT( blog_id ) FROM blog_comments WHERE blog_id = 
'$result1[id]'";
    $comments_count = mysql_query($input_now2);
    echo '<p>' . $comments_count . '</p>';  
    ?>
```

You can put something similar as above anywhere inside your loop for $result1....

Hope I have understood what your trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I understand what your saying, Maybe this would be better if I did this has an example`enter code here`....

```
    $input_now1 = "SELECT blog_entries.id, blog_entries.posted, blog_entries.subject, blog_entries.quicktext
      FROM blog_entries
      ORDER BY blog_entries.posted DESC
      LIMIT 0, 3;";

    $result1 = mysql_query($input_now1);

    $input_now2 = "SELECT COUNT( blog_id )
FROM blog_comments WHERE blog_id = 'blog_entries.id'";

    $result2 = mysql_query($input_now2);
    $record2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)
    ?>
    <div id="middle">

      <div id="box1">
        <?php
          while($record1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1))
          {
            ?> 
            <h2 style="padding-top:5px;"><?php echo $record1['subject']; ?></h2>
            <div id="header1" style="position:relative;"></div>
            <div id="maintext" style="position:relative;">
              <p><?php echo $record1['quicktext']; ?></p>
              <p>Comments: (<?php echo $record2['blog_id']; ?></p>
              <a href="blog_articles.php?ID=<?php echo $record1["id"];?>">View Article - <?php echo date("D jS F Y g:iA",strtotime($record1["posted"]));?></a>
            </div>
            <div id="text_footer"></div>
            <?php 
          }
          mysql_free_result($result1);
        ?>
      </div>
      <?php
        include 'include/sidebar.php';
      ?>        

    </div>
```

I'm sorry if I'm not clear on your end.  I been trying to figure this out for a couple of days and I don't know if I over thinking it.